# Assign Xdata For AlignedDimension

Tags: c#, autocad

I am using `AlignedDimension` object of `Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices` to create objects in autocad.
I want to store some data in `XData` of Dimension object using `TypedValue` object.
But when we assign the `resultBuffer` to `XData` it does not assign the value to `XData`.

This works fine if the object is Entity But `xData` is not getting assigned for `AlignedDimension` object.

Can you please help me assign `typedValue` to `Xdata` of `AlignedDimension`?

Below is the code snippet:

```
 List<TypedValue> xdata = new List<TypedValue>();
 xdata.Add(new TypedValue(872, "ACF"));
 DBObject object1= acTrans.GetObject(newDimension.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as Dimension;
 ResultBuffer resBuffer = new ResultBuffer(xdata.ToArray());
 object1.XData = resBuffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign xData you'll need to define a application (under RegAppTable) and use this as the first TypedValue on your list.

See a sample at http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/04/adding_xdata_to.html

```
static void AddRegAppTableRecord(string regAppName)
    {
      Document doc =
        Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
      Editor ed = doc.Editor;
      Database db = doc.Database;

      Transaction tr =
        doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
      using (tr)
      {
        RegAppTable rat =
          (RegAppTable)tr.GetObject(
            db.RegAppTableId,
            OpenMode.ForRead,
            false
          );
        if (!rat.Has(regAppName))
        {
          rat.UpgradeOpen();
          RegAppTableRecord ratr =
            new RegAppTableRecord();
          ratr.Name = regAppName;
          rat.Add(ratr);
          tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(ratr, true);
        }
        tr.Commit();
      }
    }
```